# Voice recognition (or sound)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Next week we begin a development course for iphone but in two days, I have to submit a budget in hours about how long it would take to develop a small App

The App will serve for the Deaf, which work as postmen, which at the touch of a ring (interphone) in someone Portal,needs to identify someone has answer (there has been feedback). Do not need to acknowledge what he says, but someone has spoken. If so, the phone app will launch a mp3 saying "postal letter carrier, open me please"

this has to do without Internet access.In Android, it is necessary to stream the audio go to Google's servers for proccess.We need, in the iPhone, to do so without internet access.

well ... I have have no idea yet aboud iPhone development, How do you see this app? would you help me, give me some clue?

I have to write the budget and if the clients accepts, I´ll take the course.

I would greatly appreciate any feedback. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to have an indicator that the phone detected sound I bet you could get that done in (time to create your first hello world app from scratch) + 8-16 hours.

If you want to have it filter the sound and do something based on it, give yourself + 2 weeks.

If you want to have crazy awesome talking carl like app, then give yourself +1-6 months.

Comment: thanks. I get the same, more-less, answer in another forum. Thank you too much!

Answer (score 1):

I’d say that the microphone would not be able to recognize somebody speaking behind a door with all the ambient noise you might encounter on the front side. I’m not saying it’s not possible, but I think that the success rate would be too low for the app to work decently.

Comment: Maybe that is true, but we have to try. The app needs to detect any feedback, better if it recognizes voice. By this time, Deaf people is going with another guy...that is very expensive, and makes Deaf people work innecesary... we want to give our Deaf people autonomy and this might be the way maybe.

Comment: In that case you’d better give them more control over the app. Display the sound feedback as some kind of graph, maybe make the app display a percent of confidence that the sound is a voice and supply a button that would trigger the recorded response.

Comment: that sounds great... but I need to know in how many hours this app will can be done more less, to write a budge. Can you help me with that? after that, I will have a project to develop and I will start to learn cocoa-touch, objetive-c...

Comment: Even experienced developers have hard time giving estimates. There is no way to estimate the needed effort when you are not familiar with the technologies you’ll have to use.

Comment: iap! I know, and my Boss knows but they need a budget to get some money ready for this project